# How to check weather cluster is running or not( up/not) using ADF

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a real time senario
Req:

1. I need to check weather databrick clusters is running or not
2. if not then re start the existing cluster

Problem : found that we can use web activity but in my current senario ...I am not having any access token for the existing cluster

Looking for diff approch

Answer (score 0):

You can't check status of the cluster without having a personal access token or using [Azure Active Directory token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/) (for example, by using service principal).

After you get access by using either method, you can use [Clusters Get REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters#--get) to check status of the cluster.

Comment: Help me to understand the scenario bit more please ...  I have Azure kevvault. Director I'd. Cluster I'd , databriicks url. But access token i am not able to get it... Can anyone help in it

Comment: i don't understand the question... You need service principal ID & secret, and then follow the docs to generate AAD token.